# React Native: Create tab navigator from array

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create a tab navigator from an array. I want the the tab navigator to have one tab for each item in the array. In this way, if the array is updated by user input, the tabs will update.

Here's what I have so far; I'm having trouble creating the appropriate RouteConfigs object by mapping the array.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { ListView, Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Switch, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Button, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class GroupScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>`${this.props.name}`</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

let groups = ['Group1', 'Group2']

let screens = groups.map((group) => ({
  group: { screen: GroupScreen(name = group) },
}))

export default createMaterialTopTabNavigator(screens);
```